# HTTP_HOST not found behind load balancer on EC2

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

In some requests the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` not exists. I researched on the causes and now I know that this occurs on HTTP 1.0 requests.

I have 4 domains in many machines behind a load balancer on AWS EC2 and I don't have a idea how to solve this problem.

This is important, because is a business rule.