# Undefined variable Server in Wordpress - Can't post comments

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

In my Apache2 logs I get the following error:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined variable: SERVER in /var/www/wp-comments-post.php on line 20
```

Line 20:

```
$server_name = str_replace(".", "\.", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
```

When I try to post a comment on my blog I get blank page with the URL changing to mt `domain.com/wp-comments-post.php`and therefore the comment system doesn't work.

**Update:** My wordpress is on EC2 behind an Elastic Load Balancer. I think that's the reason why the variable is not set, because it uses Alias.

How can I solve this.

Using Wordpress 3.5.2 / Apache2 / Ubuntu

Thanks.

Comment: Look at line 20 on wp-comments-post.php?

Comment: $server_name = str_replace(".", "\.", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);

Comment: Yep, sorry for that, updated the question

Comment: Why don't you update your wordpress to 3.9.2?

Comment: @dingo_d There are many things that should be updated, and the old theme is not compatible.. I've tried, was a mass.

Comment: That sucks, because I think that the new version has that sorted out better. I was looking at my wp-comments-post.php file, and the structure is different.

Comment: @dingo_d I think I know the origin of the issue, my wordpress is on EC2 behind a Load balancer. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that :\

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini for `variables_order` directive, and ensure `S` is in the string.

It should look something like this:

```
variables_order = "GPCS"
```

Comment: Yes it's there, I checked it

Comment: That's what I think.. is there a type of search to find it?

Comment: if your using an IDE, you should be able to search the project, just search for `unset($_SERVER)` otherwise you can use `grep` on CLI for unix systems.

Comment: I'm using PuTTy shell

Comment: It's in phpmyadmin/ not related to wordpress

Comment: use `grep` then, something like `grep -rn "unset(\$_SERVER)" /path/to/project`  or possibly even `grep -rn "unset(\$GLOBALS\['_SERVER'\])" /path/to/project`

Comment: both return with no results

Comment: I think I know the origin of the issue, my wordpress is on EC2 behind a Load balancer. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: $_SERVER should still be set... possibly the 'HTTP_HOST' key isn't, but you should get an undefined index error not undefined variable.. I may suggest using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] as long as the apache environment is setup to use the correct servername.

Comment: maybe I should put it manually? like: $server_name = "domain.com"?

Comment: If this is not production, I may consider doing `die('<pre>'.print_r($GLOBALS,true).'</pre>');` right at the beginning of the entry point to see exactly what is being sent to WP.

Comment: Yeah thats an idea, but its not future proof as it will break if you decide to change domain anytime in the future.

Comment: I won't change domain :)

Comment: Also its not really addressing the true issue, that the global var $_SERVER is not set, if anything else after this point needs that variable, then it won't work again..

Comment: seems I am not the only one with this issue:, but no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044630/http-host-not-found-behind-load-balancer-on-ec2

Comment: very strange. I don't know what else can be done to debug this to be honest..  seems to be isolated to amazon, don;t know whether they use an out-dated apache or something.. or something wrong with their setup!

Comment: Possibly the load balancer is stripping the Host header from the request, but this would be pretty silly on Amazons behalf..  consider printing the $GLOBALS array to see exactly what the script has been passed as previously said.  then go from there.

Comment: I will do. BTTW, maybe this also can help: in wp-config.php:
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];

Comment: I'll bet thats embedded in an `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) { ... } ` block?  if not it probably should be.  basically load balancers usually fill `X-Forwarded-Y` headers as they modify the original headers using their own information

Comment: I moved the server out of the load balancer and the issue still resides :(

Comment: :( sorry, i'm out of suggestions...  the fact that your getting undefined variable, and not undefined index for this is strange.. did you print the contents of $GLOBALS at the entry point?